# How to check if a key has been used in a custom hash table?

Tags: c, hashmap, key

I am implementing a hash table in C for a school project. I have chosen to use separate chaining with linked lists. Since I am obviously accounting for hash collisions, I am having trouble seeing how to check if a particular key has been used.

Below, is what I have so far. Obviously, it is incomplete (e.g. can't delete key-value pairs, doesn't restructure the buckets to account for the maximum load factor upon insertions, etc.). The takeaway is that I am aware of the other issues, but I just can't figure out how to check if a key has been used without storing each key somewhere.

### hash_map.h

```
#ifndef HASH_MAP_H
#define HASH_MAP_H

#include <stdint.h>

struct hash_map
{
    uintmax_t _cardinality;
    struct array_list * _buckets;
    double _max_load_factor;
    uintmax_t (* _hash_function)(void * value);
    bool (* _equality_function)(void * value1, void * value2);
};

void hash_map_set_value_for_key(struct hash_map * const map, void * const key, void * const value);
struct hash_map * hash_map_init(uintmax_t (* hash_function)(void * value), bool (* equality_function)(void * value1, void * value2));
void hash_map_destroy(struct hash_map * const map);
uintmax_t hash_map_get_cardinality(struct hash_map const * const map);
double hash_map_get_load_factor(struct hash_map const * const map);
double hash_map_get_max_load_factor(struct hash_map const * const map);

#endif //HASH_MAP_H
```

### hash_map.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hash_map.h"
#include "array_list.h"
#include "singly_linked_list.h"

void hash_map_set_value_for_key(
        struct hash_map * const map,
        void * const key,
        void * const value
)
{
    uintmax_t hash = map->_hash_function(key);
    struct singly_linked_list * const bucket = array_list_get_value_at_index(
            map->_buckets,
            hash % array_list_get_cardinality(map->_buckets)
    );

    struct singly_linked_list_node * node = singly_linked_list_get_head(bucket);
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        if (map->_equality_function(value, singly_linked_list_node_get_value(node)))
        {
            return;
        }

        node = singly_linked_list_node_get_next_node(node);
    }

    singly_linked_list_append(bucket, value);
    ++map->_cardinality;
}

void hash_map_destroy(
        struct hash_map * const map
)
{
    for (uintmax_t i = 0; i < map->_buckets->_cardinality; ++i)
    {
        singly_linked_list_destroy(array_list_get_value_at_index(map->_buckets, i));
    }

    array_list_destroy(map->_buckets);

    free(map);
}

uintmax_t hash_map_get_cardinality(
        struct hash_map const * const map
)
{
    return map->_cardinality;
}

double hash_map_get_load_factor(
        struct hash_map const * const map
)
{
    return (double) map->_cardinality / array_list_get_cardinality(map->_buckets);
}

double hash_map_get_max_load_factor(
        struct hash_map const * const map
)
{
    return map->_max_load_factor;
}

struct hash_map * hash_map_init(
        uintmax_t (* hash_function)(void *),
        bool (* equality_function)(void *, void *)
)
{
    struct hash_map * const map = malloc(sizeof(struct hash_map));

    map->_cardinality = 0;
    map->_max_load_factor = 0.7;
    map->_hash_function = hash_function;
    map->_equality_function = equality_function;

    map->_buckets = array_list_init();
    array_list_append(map->_buckets, singly_linked_list_init());

    return map;
};
```

Comment: Compute the hash for the key. Go to the appropriate bucket. Walk the linked list to see if the key is in the list.

Comment: Just what was said above.  When walking the linked list for the bucket, you need to do an ordinary string compare on the keys to see if there's a key match.

Comment: "I just can't figure out how to check if a key has been used without storing each key somewhere". That's because you do indeed have to store each key.

Comment: I see now that you're calling `map->_hash_function(value)`, and the `hash_map_set_value_for_key` function never once uses the `key`. I suggest that you go back to start, and study what a [hash map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) does. You need to hash the key, and then store the key/value pair in the linked list.

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. I meant to hash the key. Thanks!